# How to get folders name from sub domain?

Tags: php

```
<?php
 $dir = "http://www.test.oddly.co";
 if (is_dir($dir)){
 if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
 while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
   echo "filename:" . $file . "<br>";
 }
 rewinddir();  
 closedir($dh);
 }
}
?>
```

This is my code. There are some folders. That URL sub domain contain that  folders. I want to get that folders name and insert into the array. But my code is not shoeing anything. How can I get that folders name from that domain?

Comment: Your script doesn‘t show anything because a url isn‘t a diectory.

Comment: It doesn't work in this way. Remote domains isn't a local directory you can read from.

Comment: Okay. I understand. But this is the root. This URL contains folders. May be hidden. So, How can I get that folders name?

Comment: This is an url. This is the root. www.test.oddly.co It contains folders. I want to scan this and get the folders name. How to do that. www.test.oddly.co/liocdev/register/ In this www.test.oddly.co is the root, liocdev is the folder. How to get all the folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URLs are not directories. They cannot be treated as directories.

`http://www.test.oddly.co` purports to be an HTML document, but it has no content. It contains no clues as to what other URLs the server might support.

If you want to find out what other URLs a webserver hosts for a given hostname, you need to find a source of data that will tell you. This could be scraping the HTML on the website or using a search engine to perform a search like [site:www.test.oddly.co](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3Awww.test.oddly.co&oq=site%3Awww.test.oddly.co&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.1962j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) in the hope that there is information about available URLs published by a third party.

Comment: Yes. This is an url.  This is the root. www.test.oddly.co It contains folders. I want to scan this and get the folders name. How to do that. www.test.oddly.co/liocdev/register/
In this  www.test.oddly.co is the root, liocdev is the folder.
How to get all the folders?

Comment: @SabbirHossain — I'll repeat my answer in simpler terms: **You can't**

Comment: - I can't. Using cURL also can't?

Comment: An HTTP client is an HTTP client. It cannot magically conjure information that the server does not give it. No, cURL won't solve the problem.

Comment: Ohh I see. Thank you.